# scanf() function does not work?

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I program the basic struct with other functions.But I wrong something.

```
printf("\nPlease Enter New Salary: ");
scanf("%lf",A[i].salary);
```

but scanf does not work?
How do ı work it?

Comment: Blind guess: `scanf("%lf",A[i].salary)` --> `scanf("%lf",&(A[i].salary))`

Comment: "Does not work" is not a technical term. If you want to be a developer, explain the problem in detail.

Comment: Well, one of two possibilities exist. Either _scanf() function does not work_, as you seem to be suggesting, or _poster doesn't know how to use scanf() and needs to be told what s/he is doing wrong_. If it's the first case, there's nothing to post because the function is simply broken. If it's the second, you should consider posting more of your code since what you posted is insufficient (though it's probable that changing the code to `scanf("%lf",&A[i].salary);` will fix you up).

Comment: I'm a student now not DEVELOPER,I hope I'm a developer in future :)

Comment: I understand I found my fault :( Thanks Everybody

Answer (score 1):

The `scanf` function expects a pointer to `double` as argument for the `"%lf"` format specifier.  You instead pass the value of `A[i].salary`.

You did not post the definition of `A`, if it is an array or a pointer to an array of structures whose member `salary` is a `double`, you can get the proper behavior by writing:

```
if (scanf("%lf", &A[i].salary) == 1) {
    /* value was converted properly */
} else {
    /* input stream cannot be parsed as a double */
}
```

You should configure your environment to compile with extra warnings enabled: for example `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` or `clang -Weverything -Werror` would produce a diagnostic for this kind of error and compilation would fail.

Comment: I understand I found my fault :( Thanks ;)